# Render a select box as radios buttons in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to show select box options as raido buttons in Django Admin change model view. I don't want to write custom model forms. I'm looking for a way to render some select boxes as radio buttons while keeping auto generated model forms of the Django admin. I'm using django v 1.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `my_field` is the field, we want to be rendered as `Radio Button`

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

from .models import MyModel

class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {'my_field': forms.RadioSelect}

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a widget from select box into radio buttons you can use a "quick-and-dirty" way to change all widgets for specific field type globally as stated by [Django 5.0 Admin Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides), without having to write a custom form model.

As example for ForeignKey fields that are rendered as select boxes by default you could do the following:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect

from .models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ForeignKey: {"widget": RadioSelect},
    }
    
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

This effects also all other ForeignKey field inputs which could be an issue, and also widgets for fields that have been set to be editable in list view using list_editable attribute in MyModelAdmin class declaration which would not be affected by subclassing ModelForm in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666240/1669514).